# Password Maker Python Lists

Tags: python, for-loop, passwords

```
This program is supposed to prompt the user to make a password, however only 
certain characters are allowed to be used. 
def password(z):
    n=0
    w=0
    a=0
    b=['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','?']
    c=['.',',',':',';','[',']','{','}','(',')','<','>','|','~','-
       ','=','+','_']
    for ch in z:
        if any(ch in c for ch in z):
            z=raw_input("Illegal characters. Please try again: ")
            return password(z)
        else:
            if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in z):
                n+=1
            if any(ch in b for ch in z):
                w+=1
            if any(ch.isalpha() for ch in z):
                a+=1
            if n==0 or w==0 or a==0:
                m=raw_input("Please use at least one letter, number, and special character: \n")
                return password(m)
            if n>0 and w>0 and a>0:
                y=raw_input("Please retype password: ")
            if y==z:
                print "Password confirmed"
                break
            else:
                y=raw_input("Not the same password. Please create a new password: ")
                return password(y)

z=raw_input('Enter a password: ')
print password(z)
```

UPDATE: This now works. I'm however a bit confused as to why it does, since I don't know why I needed to put the any method for ch in b, cause I thought that if ch in b means that if any ch is in the list b. Regardless, it now works.

Comment: The code in your question is indented incorrectly (starting at `if y==z`) -- it won't run in a Python interpreter. Please include the _exact_ code you're using in the question.

Comment: There are so many problems with this function, you should probably rewrite it from scratch rather than try to fix it. Your use of recursion and loops is quite confusing. You're doing _way too much_ inside of this loop. A simple password checking function shouldn't need more than 3 indents, and it definitely shouldn't need recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns `None`, because you have no `return` statements at all.  `None` is the default return value.  Your logic is somewhat convoluted, especially the superfluous recursion, but I *think* you can fix this by simply adding

```
return z
```

to the bottom of the function.

---

FOLLOW-UP

I revisited this ... and your logic appears to have a variety of problems.

- Your indentation is faulty near the bottom of the loop; this code won't reach execution.
- int() always returns 0.  I think you want ch.isdigit() here
- You check each character for being 0, then in the "b" list, then in the "c" list ... and as soon as you find all three, you move on to confirming the password.  Is that the logic flow you wanted?

Also ...

- Single-letter variable names have very little information.  Use descriptive ones.
- For simple exists / doesn't exist variables, use Boolean, not 0 and 1.  Again, this will make your code easier to read.
- If you change `b` and `c` to strings, the code will be easier to read, and your `in` statements will still work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function returns None, is because your function doesn't return anything when it is successful.

Also, even if you did add a return statement, your check for integers is not correct. one correct way to check this would be ch.isdigit()